# "Injecting" a WHERE clause dynamically w/ PetaPoco

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, multi-tenant, petapoco

I'm building a multi-tenant app with a shared database using .NET MVC 3 and PetaPoco. 
The tenant id (along with other info) is saved in a FormsAuth cookie on login and is available to all controllers via a BaseController property. Most tables, (i.e. apart from apart the main 'Tenants' table) include a TenantId column.

Instead of manually adding a 'WHERE TenantId = X' to all CRUD on the feature tables, is there a way I can dynamically add this to the query just before its executed? In other words, maybe maintain a list of tables, and if the query is for one of those tables, then dynamically add in the TenantId filter?

The benefit of course is that it removes the need to add in the filter manually thus reducing the chances its left out. I did find an [example using NHibernate](http://www.agileatwork.com/bolt-on-multi-tenancy-in-asp-net-mvc-with-unity-and-nhibernate-part-ii-commingled-data/), which I doubt can be repurposed. I am using Ninject in case that makes a difference.

Comment: What kind of data you are trying to store with your app.  There may be security/ SQL injection risks in using dynamic SQL in this way

Comment: In general yes, but we're really using parameterized sql (PetaPoco does so by default), so that shouldn't be an issue. I didn't mention it in the post as its not relevant to the actual question. But thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Good deal.  I'm not familiar with PetaPoco so I cringed at first when I saw that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an OnCommandExecuting method on the Database class which you can override in your own sub class, and modify the sql as you wish just before it gets executed. We use this feature for converting isnull/nvl between Sql Server and Oracle.

You could just leave a marker in your sql and replace it here.

Comment: Thanks - that would work. However, it could get tricky if the IDbCommand has JOINs and you'd only want the filter to be applied to certain tables. The marker would possibly overcome that, except that if I'm adding the marker in the sql, I might as well add in the TenantId filter directly (as the 'problem' of a developer forgetting to 'add' would still exist). I think I might opt for a GetByTenant (vs. a 'Get') in the base repository instead, unless there are better solutions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: True, but you could also check if the marker is there if a certain table is mentioned and throw an exception otherwise. I have also used a helper function which tacks on a exists clause and in the clause I use a comment /*SECURITY*/ etc and then check this before executing otherwise throw an exception.